# java : String to JSON order changed

Tags: java

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class TestFile {

    public static void main(String d[]) throws Exception{

            String ch = "{'r':1,'is':'abc'}";

            JSONObject js  = new JSONObject(ch);

            System.out.println(js);

        }
}
```

When i run this program it the JSONObject prints `{"is":"abc","r":1}`, but i want in the same order of which the original string as it is.

please help me.

Thanks.

Regards
S.Chinna

Answer (score 2):

Hash tables (JSON "objects") do not maintain key order. This is by design.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that order is preserved, see Standard ECMA-262.

If you insist, try

```
{"data":{'r':1,'is':'abc'}, "ordering":['r','is']}
```

and iterate over ordering to lookup key in data.